# How to collect in a list all the references for every cells in an Excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I've got a huge Excel 2010 file with several Worksheets to modify. I'd like to collect all the references, because I don't want to ruin the Excel file, when I modify some cells, etc.

Example file:

```
B2 = A2 + A3
B5 = B2
```

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
Worksheet1!A2 -> Worksheet1!B2
Worksheet1!A3 -> Worksheet1!B2
Worksheet1!B2 -> Worksheet1!B5
```

How can I do something like this in Excel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Display the relationships between formulas and cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) does not help?

Comment: @Axel +1 for reminding us of a great tool that people too-often forget about

Answer (score 2):

A much much much better (and easier) idea would be to use **Backup** copies.  If it stops working, do you plan on double checking every single cell compared to your custom text output of the cells?

Then, any time you make a few changes, check if everything still works.  If not, revert.

If you're really concerned, you can [set AutoRecover to create a new copy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-save-a-backup-copy-of-a-workbook-9b947d35-f218-4238-be39-04668b0975eb) ever 60 seconds.  (Don't worry about using up disk space; you can periodically delete unneeded backups with a couple clicks.)